# Internationalization in MFC

Tags: c++, unicode, mfc, localization, internationalization

It's finally (after years of postponing) the time to localize my app in a few other languages other than English.

The first challenge is to design the integration into my C++ / MFC application that has dozens of dialogs and countless strings. I came across two possible alternative implementations:

1. Compile and deploy localized resource files as DLLs
2. Extract and replace all strings with the localized version. For each 
   language there will be an XML (or simple text) file.

Personally I opt for the second alternative since it seems to me more flexible. The changes are many but not hard to make, and very importantly the XML files will be very easy to modify for the translators.

Any advise is greatly appreciated.

Regards,
Cosmin Unguru
http://www.batchphoto.com/

Comment: Is this question transposable to newer MFC versions in newer Visual versions? What is the best way to create multi language MFC projects? Does is solve the translation problem (to do not use RCLocalize)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I did some long-living MFC projects with different languages. 
I strongly recommend the first approach with resource-only DLLs.

The reasons:

(1) If the user does a XCOPY install, he always has the default language (English) in the main executables.

(2) If you don't translate everything (e.g. you're late with your release or forget some strings), the Windows resource functions if properly used return the resource in the default language automatically - you don't have to implement it on your own.

(3) My very person opinion: (a) Line breaks, tabs, whitespaces in XML files are a pain in your a**. (b) Merging XML files is even worse...

(4) Don't forget the encoding. It's okay in XML but your translators might use an unsuitable editor and damage the file.

And now for the main reason:

(5) You will have to rearrange many of your dialogs, because many strings are longer in e.g. French or German than in English. And making all statics, buttons, ... larger "just in case" looks crappy.

Another hint: Spend some bucks and buy one of the translation tools which import your projects / binaries and build up a translation database. This will be amortized after the first release.

Another hint (2): If possible make a release which doesn't contain any changes but only the multi-language feature. Also in future, if possible: Release your product in English. Then do the translation in one single step (per language) and release the other languages.

Comment: What translation tools would you recommend for C++/MFC?

Comment: @Cosmin: Sorry, can't recommend any because I used them later with Windows Forms, not MFC. For WinForms we used VisLoc (http://visloc.com/index.php?id=6&L=2). I was happy with it, but after I left the company, they changed to Catalyst (http://www.alchemysoftware.ie/index.html). These tools are not cheap but their money worth (if they support MFC / your application).

Answer (score 5):

My good and friendly suggestion from somebody who worked a lot with localization:

1. Grab GNU Gettext,
2. Mark all your strings as _("English").
3. Extract all strings using gettext tool xgettext and compile dictionalries
4. Translate string using great tools like poedit.
5. Use gettext in your project and make your localization life simpler!

You can also use `boost::locale` for same purpose - it uses GNU Gettext dictionaries and approach but provides different and more powerful runtime and for windows developer it has very good addon - it supports wide strings that MFC requires to use for normal Unicode support.

Don't use resources and other "translation" tools that are total crap from linguistic point of view (and developer's point of view as well).

Further reading: http://cppcms.sourceforge.net/boost_locale/html/tutorial.html

Comment: I didn't down vote this, but I could guess. GNU Gettext has one problematic property: the license. It's GPL. Not L-GPL, but GPL (at least on Windows). Which simply means that you'd have to release your application with compatible license as well (in other words open source it).

Comment: @Paweł Dyda read the license, tools are GPL but the runtime itself is LGPL, also boost::locale uses gettext dictionaries not requiring linking with GNU code. So you don't have any issues with that.

Comment: If MFC, are not all the texts already in a .rc file? (by design)

Comment: @Sandburg it is exactly the problem - you can't see the text in code - it becomes maintenance nightmare. Separating message text and code isn't very good idea.

Answer (score 4):

Using a DLL resource library is a relatively straightforward operation, and allows you to manage not only strings, but other resources as well. And this is its main advantage, because i18n [is not only about string translation](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/08/17/10050774.aspx).

However, depending on your needs, a text-based solution may be a better decision, because of its easier handling - resource scripts being more complex than xml files, especially for the average translator.

I would suggest creating your own abstraction layer, something like "LoadLocalizedString", etc.; in this way, you can start implementing it just with text files, and then change to something more complex when and if required in a transparent way - all the effort for making your software i18n aware would still be valid.

Answer (score 2):

In our case we had diffrent dialogues per Language. The resource file was the same as the multiple laguages were implemented at development time. You could basically append on existing resource files the diferent languages. I hope it helps to find your way.

Comment: That is rather wasteful as you are loading languages that are never used.  There is no need to have translation X, Y, and Z, loaded into memory if the user only wants to see translation Y.

Comment: I know, though the archtecture is not mine :)

Answer (score 1):

The DLL option is commonly used for this since the resource loading procedure (e.g. LoadLibrary) is already written - meaning you don't have to write any parsing/loading code.  While XML is easier to edit, DLLs have a bit more security (users won't be able to easily edit them) and will allow the developer (meaning you) more time to work on application logic instead of writing a language loading system.

```
HMODULE hLangDLL = LoadLibrary("text_en.dll");
// more stuff
TCHAR mybuffer[1024] = {0};
LoadString(hLangDLL, IDS_MYSTRING, mybuffer, 1023);
```

Comment: Though in this implementation you have to implement every string?

Comment: You have to translate every string in either case.  The XML option allows you to quickly edit the file with the strings in them, but you have to load the strings into a custom data structure to get access.  The DLL option allows you to use the built in resource loading functions so the only thing that changes is which DLL you load for the language strings.  Each DLL must have the same ID's assigned to translated strings - so in the example, if I changed to text_de.dll, IDS_MYSTRING would be the Dannish translation for whatever was in that resource.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the clarification. I think this is the proper way though the the hardest as (more code) as well ;)

Comment: "Meaning you don't have to write any parsing/loading code" - Do you mean, loading the XML file? This is so easy to do that it doesn't even count.

Comment: Are you saying it is more code for the DLL method?  If so, that is inaccurate.  To localize via DLL (not counting the settings GUI you'll want to create to allow users to switch the language at runtime - which is consistent between either method), it is a single line of code to change the language (the LoadLibrary call).  Using the XML method, you have to create your own resource cache to hold the strings loaded in from XML.  Even if you use a third party (e.g. Xerces) XML parser that supports XPath, you are still looking at a good 100-200 lines of code just to load and manage the strings.

Comment: @Cosmin:  Its not just the loading code (which, despite being easy, still is more work than simply calling LoadLibrary), it is also the management of the strings.  Unless you plan to hold the XML parser in memory for your entire application (rather wasteful), you'd typically load the strings into some data structure that you can easily access them from (e.g. a map).  You'll need to manage that map yourself.  DLLs already have all that work done for you.  Either method will work (and I have used both in different circumstances), but the DLL method gives you a far quicker time to market.

Comment: @Zac, creating a "resource cache" (e.g. a map of identifiers to strings) is minutes work.  It can be edited and reloaded without recompilation of a resource DLL is is easily edited without Visual Studio, using any text-editor you wish.  For an App that is localizing just the strings, XML is definitely the way to go and DLLs are, imy humble opinion, complete overkill.

Comment: @Moo-Juice:  You miss the point entirely.  Writing a max function is easy; does that mean you will write your own every time you need one?  A resource system (a fairly lightweight one mind you) already exists in the form of Windows DLLs.  Unless this is application has to be able to compile on another platform as well, XML is more work for no added benefit - no matter how you slice it.

Comment: @Zac, we are not dealing with the trivialities of 'max', here and the comparison is not appropriate.  A (simple) custom system automatically supports runtime language-change, should it be needed, a more verbose format, and far easier for the translators to work on.

Comment: I've been here and the writing of your own resource cache while not trivial, isn't exactly hard. BTW - I didn't use xml, but used uris - app.dialog.string - which also allowed me to use the positioning code I had already written - app.dialog.top, app.dialog.left, etc.

Comment: @Moo-Juice:  The comparison is approprite - you are encouraging someone to reinvent the wheel.  While there are times when writing your own logic to do X is necessary (e.g. if you needed to cross-compile this on Linux and MacOS as well), but assuming you are only running this application on Windows, there is no benefit to doing so.  You spend more time writing code instead of using code that is already built and well-tested.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4398402/internationalization-in-mfc/4398879#4398879 for more reasons.

Comment: @Zac, the "reinvent the wheel" discussion is one for another day although I largely agree with it (there are other caveats) :)  Don't get me wrong, I see the need for resource DLLs too, but I also believe XML has its place (cross-platform or not), and the code to implement it is trivial.  As for benefits, aside from what I mentioned, it is far easier to send a translator an XML file than it is to send them a resource file.  We may agree to disagree on this, but I believe both have their place.

Comment: @Moo-Juice:  As I stated, I have done both in commercial products.  Your primary logic behind saying to use XML is that it is easy to have translators work directly on those assets (on most commercial products, you don't want that anyway, but that is another discussion entirely).  My primary points are:  If you are using Windows, the system already exists which will meet your need with 2 lines of code, so why write far more than that to accomplish the same thing in an untested way?  EDIT:  And it is very common in commercial products to use language DLLs for this.

Answer (score 0):

If it is just the strings that are changing then I agree that XML is the way forward here for the exact reasons you outline.  Easy for other people to edit, easy to change language at runtime, etc.

The only reason (in my eyes) that you'd choose option 1 is if things other than strings are being localized such as needing different icons.

If it's just text?  I say go with the XML.

Comment: @Cosmin, then I'd definitely go with the XML.  It's trivial to load and put in a map of some sort.