# Override LoadString for MFC app

Tags: c++, mfc, localization, internationalization

I have a static-linked MFC app I'm trying to localise.  For convenience I would prefer to have all strings sourced from XML files.  I've already set this up for the rest of my app.  However, MFC retrieves some strings from string resources internally, presumably via `LoadString`.  Is it possible to override this so I can reimplement it to source strings from XML files?

I've already tried creating a DLL which implements LoadString, but it only is called for calls to LoadString from my own code (which I've already replaced), and is not called from the MFC library code.  I could try updating the resources, but it seems kind of hackish.  Is it possible to redirect where LoadString finds its strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure how to override LoadString but the most commonly used approach for localization is to create Resource DLL's and use it. Refer [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11731/Resource-DLLs-and-Language-Selection-Menu).

For the merits of using Resource DLL's read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4398402/462467)